# How to check class equality in Python 2.5?

Tags: python, class, equality, python-2.5

I've looked through Python 2.5 documentation and I couldn't find an answer to this: How do I check if an object is the same class as another object?

```
def IsClass(obj1, obj2):
     return obj1.class == obj2.class #doesn't work
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
type(obj1) is type(obj2)
```

Note that you usually try to avoid type checking in Python, but rather rely on [duck typing](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-duck-typing).

Comment: The last sentence should be in bold. And red if markdown supported that. This can't be streched enough. If you believe you need this, you most propably don't and should just use duck tying.

Comment: You should also consider using `issubclass()` or `isinsntance()` when you do care about actual types, since in most cases when you are looking for a `foo`, you would also accept a subclass of `foo`.

Comment: It's been a long time, but do you recall what version of Python you used to test your answer? Maybe you should add a big fat note that the answer may not apply to other versions.
 
E.g. it won't work for Python 2.7 (the default in many systems as of 2016). But it does work with Python 3.4 and 3.5.

Comment: @m000: This definitely works in Python 2.7.  It should actually work in any version of Python, ever.  Note that this checks for type identity, which in isn't what you want in most situations.  Also read the first two comments on this answer.

Comment: @SvenMarnach The problem seems to be *old* vs *new* style classes.  https://wiki.python.org/moin/NewClassVsClassicClass

I used this test code: http://pastebin.com/nmpYJdGJ

For python 2.7, `type(obj)` comparison works only with *new style* classes. I.e. your classes have to extend `object`. Old style classes have been superseded since python 2.2 but there's no warning from the interpreter when using them.
Comparing `__class__` property seems to work irrespectively of the style of the classes.

Answer (score -1):

I think what you want to do is use type(obj). :)

-EDIT- Looks like he beat me to it. And he's right about the Duck Typing.